# Javascript Promise: Why is caught Exception still logged as uncaught?

Tags: javascript, promise

when I build my Promise and call the fail function, the error should be caught by the .catch function for the promise right? But in the console.log I still get it as uncaught (also the .catch  function get triggered). Why? Or is this intended? I think I get something conceptually wrong and would like to be enlightened!

Consider the following example:

```
var A = {
  loadingPromise: null,
  loadingPromiseFail: null,
  loadingPromiseResolver: null,

  init: function() {
    this.loadingPromise = new Promise(
      function(resolve, fail) {
        this.loadingPromiseResolver = resolve;
        this.loadingPromiseFail = fail;
      }.bind(this)
    );

    this.loadingPromise.then(function(data) {
      console.log('success');
    }.bind(this));

    this.loadingPromise['catch'](function(e, x) {     
      console.log('error', e);
    }.bind(this));
  },

  doSomething: function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
     this.loadingPromiseFail('404');
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  }

}

A.init();
A.doSomething();
```

console.log:

```
error 404
uncaught exception: 404
```

Why is the second?

Also here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Paflow/4g7yj38b/6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bit of code

```
this.loadingPromise.then(function(data) {
  console.log('success');
}.bind(this));
```

has no catch, so the error is indeed uncaught

This is how you should write your code to use Promises correctly

```
var A = {
  loadingPromise: null,
  loadingPromiseFail: null,
  loadingPromiseResolver: null,

  init: function() {
    this.loadingPromise = new Promise(
      function(resolve, fail) {
        this.loadingPromiseResolver = resolve;
        this.loadingPromiseFail = fail;
      }.bind(this)
    );

    this.loadingPromise.then(function(data) {
      console.log('success');
    }.bind(this)).catch(function(e, x) {
      console.log('error', e);
    }.bind(this));
  },

  doSomething: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.loadingPromiseFail('404');
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  }

}

A.init();
A.doSomething();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4g7yj38b/7/

The point is, that you can add more than one .then (and indeed .catch) to a Promise ... each "chain" is independent, so you *should* have a .catch on each "chain" to avoid this console error, even though this has no real impact on the rest of the code

Comment: Okay, thank you I didn't thought of the catch()-function as something attached to a then()-function, but something existing on the same level. Most likely I would have expected, that you can add several catch()-functions as well, and in case of any fail, all would be called. As I thought, some conceptually misunderstanding. Thank you for explaning that!